# data sampling methods in the R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

Sampling the dataset in data science to build the predictive model is pretty important .suggest me good resource for data sampling in the  R language and good package for it

Comment: Resource requests are actually off-topic for Stack Overflow. But if you search for any particular sampling method in R, you will find lots of examples.

Comment: I suggest you to read the following document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Gregor then suggest for stratified sampling and implementation in r

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo i know it .

Comment: Show what you have tried! Searching the [tag:r] tag for "stratified sample" gives 189 questions. Have you looked at any of them, tried any of them? [Here's the search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+stratified+sample). What did you try, what didn't work, what more do you need? A request for a tutorial is not a good question for stack overflow. Get a data set. Try something. When you get stuck, share you data, share what you tried, and we will help get you the rest of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `caret` package.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(3456)
trainIndex <- caret::createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .8, # partition 80%~20%
                                         list = FALSE, 
                                         times = 1)
```

https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html

But realize that **StackOverflow** is a place for sharing ideas and knowledge about codes, I suggest you check out the link below for best use.

[How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)